# jquery get not passing values

Tags: php, jquery

My html form:

```
<input id="captcha_response" name="captcha_response" type="text" value="" size="5" maxlength="5">    
<div class="new_comment"><input id="comment" name="comment" type="text" value="your comment here..."></div>
    <div class="author"><input name="name" type="text" value="your name"></div>
    <div class="email"><input name="email" type="text" value="email"></div>
```

My jquery:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "ajax/check_captcha.php",
   data: ({ captcha : captcha , comment:comment , name:name, email:email }), dataType: "json", success: function(data)
    {
```

This is returning a 'not enough arguments' error in firebug.

It was working with just the 'captcha' value being passed but no longer.

Email seems to be the value that is not being passed on.

Comment: Are you missing some of your code there? It can hardly end with a {

Comment: No, I know the function works. I am just adding on more pieces of data. Originally it was just captcha:captcha

Comment: Is the 2nd "captcha" a variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said that they are form names? Yet, have you defined them as variables. Couldn't tell since you don't show the rest of your script.

```
data: { 
    captcha : $("input[name='captca_response']").val(), 
    comment : $("input[name='comment']").val(), 
    name : $("input[name='name']").val(), 
    email: $("input[name='email']").val()
}
```

Try something like that, so that you actually return the values of the inputs.

Answer (score 2):

try removing the two `(` and `)` in data, just like this

```
data: { captcha : captcha , comment:comment , name:name, email:email },
```

if your html inputs are on a `<form>` tag, it would be easier to use [.serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) and let jquery get all the data,...

like this

```
data: $('#fomID').serialize(), 
// this will build something like 
// "captcha=captchaData&comment=newComment&name=name&email=email@email.en"
```

Comment: That at least gives me the FireBug error: email is not defined.

Comment: if that's the case, you may be not defining email variable?